# How to change an array's value using PHP's own functions

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
$result = array(
    0 => array(
      "title" => "I am a hero!",
      "cat" => "literature",
      "date" => "23/7/2014",
   ),
   1 => array(
      "title" => "Significant Moment!",
      "cat" => "psychology",
      "date" => "29/7/2014",
   ),
   2 => array(
      "title" => "Coins do not count",
      "cat" => "economy",
      "date" => "23/7/2014",
   ),
);
```

Well now I want to loop through the array, recursively, and check if the current key is 
"title", then please change its value. Some thing like this:

```
for(looping $result)
{
  if($current_key == "title")
  {
     $result[$current_key] = "Now title is change";
  }
}
```

I want to use PHP's array functions for this. I think `array_walk_recursive` is the choice for this. I have tried the following code, but it changes every value and not just the corresponding key:

```
array_walk_recursive($results, function(&$item, $key) use(&$results){

                if($key == "title");
                {
                    $item = "Title Changed";
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why don't you use `foreach` for this ?

Comment: I already have stated I want to use PHP's built-in functions since they're much more faster. If I wanted to use loops, I would go with for and not foreach

Comment: Maybe the built in functions are faster, but does it really make a difference to you? This is a trivial example, but in more complicated situations you shouldn't avoid using foreach for this reason, unless the performance increase is measurable and important in the context of your application. Making micro-optimisations at the cost of readable code is inadvisable: If you really need this kind of performance, PHP may not be the best choice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is good but you have semicolon at the and of if-statement line, so "if" is ignored

```
        array_walk_recursive($results, function(&$item, $key) use(&$results){
            printer($key, true, false, false);
            if($key == "title") {
                $item = "Title Changed";
            }
        });
```

Comment: Oh I see. what a nasty typo there. Thanks so much. It now works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to walk this array recursively since you already know the depth of it.

My recommendation will be to use a simple for loop:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($result); $i++)
    $result[$i]['title'] = "Now title is change";
```

if you really insist using `array_` functions you can use PHP's [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) like this:

```
array_walk($result, function(&$a, $key){
    $a['title'] = "Now title is change";
});
```

([**Working example**](https://eval.in/216146))

Comment: What benefit will you get from PHP's functions?

Comment: the array has more than three elements, near ten elements with a lot of records. Using foreach is never suggested over PHP's own functions. PHP's own functions executes your code within C loop, while Foreach must be first interpreted and then be taken into a C loop. It takes more computing resources, also, within PHP itself, for is always preferred over foreach.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't miss something, it seems for me that what you want to achieve is a simple mapping...

So you can do it with the [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function :

```
<?php

// $result = ...

$new_result = array_map(
    function($item){
        $item["title"] = "Now title is change";
        return $item;
    },
    $result
);

// Now $new_result is what you want.
```